# Insert node at a certain position in a linked list in c

Tags: c, linked-list

```
typedef struct list{
      int number;
      struct list *next;
    }LIST;

    void p(struct list *head, int pos, int data){
         struct list *p=head, *q, *p_n=NULL;
         int i=1;

        p_n = (struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
        p_n->number=data;

        while ((p->next!=NULL) && (i!=pos)) {
            i++;
            p=p->next;
        } 

        if(p->next==NULL){
        p_n->next=NULL;
        p->next = p_n;
        else{
        q=p->next;
        p->next=p_n;
        p_n->next=q;
        }
    }
```

hi people., i need som help. function p should insert data to linked list at a specific position. Everithing is fine, but this function is inserting data to position+1, and i dont know why. i will be very thankful, if you wold me help.

Thank you :)

Comment: You need help? How about you help *us* first and indent your code in a sane way?

Comment: Did you run the code using a debugger, tracing it step by step inspecting all relevant variables to see what **really** happens?

Comment: This will work fine if you consider position to start from zero.

Comment: Why can't you just subtract 1 from `pos` at the start of the routine?

Comment: simply subtract one from the position...its easy.

Answer (score 0):

You may start  with *i=0* instead of 1!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few points you should take care of.

1. You should be passing `struct list **headp` rather than `struct list *head`, and access the information using `*headp`. Only then the changes made to `head` in your function will reflect in your calling function.
2. What will happen when you are inserting your first element? Your head will be `NULL` and accessing `p->next` will give you a Segmentation Fault in Linux. So you should be checking for `NULL` before doing anything else, and if it is not `NULL` then only proceed to next step. If it is `NULL`, you should directly assign the new node to `head`.
3. What exactly is the point of `typedef`ing the `struct` if you are not using it?

This is what happens when you run your code. Say you are inserting at i<sup>th</sup> position. You will find the i<sup>th</sup> node and will add the new node to the right of it. This will make the new node i+1<sup>th</sup>.

Instead you can find the i-1<sup>th</sup> node and insert the node to it's right. Change the condition in the while loop as `p->next!=NULL && i<pos`

Good Luck!